# MapActivity instance management

Tags: android, mapactivity

I have a `MapActivity` subclass and I want to preserve the stack, but I can't keep multiple instances of a `MapActivity` in the same process. So I have come up with 2 schemes to achieve this:

1. Pass the state of the `MapActivity` along with any intents it fires and then let the activities that get switched to reconstruct the `MapActivity` by sending an intent that recreates the activity. Additionally, the `MapActivity` would be set so that intents only ever create a single instance of this activity at a time. This approach is flawed as there are multiple exit paths from this activity so all of them would need to be changed to support this.
2. Replace the `MapActivity` with a mock activity that does the recreation of the activity in it's `onResume()` method or something and then the activities you switch to can remain blissfully unaware of this issue. The problem with this approach is I am unaware about how I should go about creating this mock activity and also fire an intent to start the activity I want to switch to.

So my question is this is there a better way to do this and, if not, how would I go about doing option 2, if it is possible?

EDIT: One possible way to do option 2 is to make the mock activity a waypoint that starts the target activity for you in it's `onCreate()`. But then one just has to be careful that if the `onCreate()` gets called again because the activity is being reconstructed, that one doesn't start the target activity again. This can be done by checking that `savedInstanceState` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SingleInstance attribute in the manifest file, this will bring the earlier launched instance to the top of the backstack

```
<activity android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```

Comment: Yes I am planning on doing this, but what I want to do is preserve the back stack. So if A is the map and B is another activity and the user navigates A->B->A->B->A. I want it to appear to the user that the back stack is ABABA. But I want to achieve this without actually having multiple instances of A. This is the hard part.